# How do you edit the command line php.ini file in Azure?

Tags: php, azure, memcached, command-line-interface

I'm trying to migrate a PHP website from AWS to Azure and have created a website in the Azure UI.

I've installed composer using the Kudu console and have overridden a few php.ini settings via the .user.ini file I created in the root. I've also added `php_memcache.dll` to my wwwroot/bin directory and enabled this in app settings within the Azure UI.

However, when running `composer install` using using the console I get an error because it can't find the memcache library. I assume because I haven't added this to the command line php.ini file. Does anyone know how to to edit this?

This is the error I get when I run `composer install`:

`- The requested PHP extension ext-memcache * is missing from your system.`

**Edit - Solution**

Looks like I've managed to run `composer install` using the following command:

`php -d extension=D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_memcache.dll bin\composer.phar install`

Is it possible to run this without specifying the extension and using `composer install` instead of bin\composer.phar install`?

Answer (score 1):

To add an extension to PHP app on an Azure website, it is easier to configure it from your Azure portal. The official Azure documentation on [PHP configuration](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/) should help, just search on that page for "How to: Enable extensions in the default PHP runtime".

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to get CLI extensions onto Azure.  I did find that 

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Does the install without blocking on missing PHP extensions.